# "∀x, p(x) or ∀x, q(x)" if "or" in math is always an "inclusive or" unless specified, what does that sentence mean?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

$$∀x, p(x) ∨ ∀x, q(x)$$
let's say that p(x) means "is blue" and q(x) "is red".

if the "or" is an inclusive or, that means that, we can say "everything is blue or everything is red or everything is blue and red"

what does that "blue and red" mean? that every single object has 2 colors blue and red, or between all the objects I have, there are some red objects and blue objects?

this is getting me crazy I've been on this "everything this or that" and "everything this or everything that" all day.

if it's the latter, that is "between all the objects I have, there are some red objects and blue object" how is it different from

$$∀x, p(x) ∨ q(x)$$

which means "everything is blue or red or both blue and red"?

thank you!

Comment: Your first formula means either everything is blue or everything is red.

Comment: With $p(x)$ as "is delicious" and $q(x)$ is "is cheap" and the universe is the set of ice creams available for purchase, $\forall x, p(x)\vee q(x)$ reads "*Every ice cream is delicious or it is cheap.*"  Now... there are some ice creams which are delicious but expensive.  There are some ice creams which are cheap and taste bad.  There are also some ice creams which are cheap and are also delicious.  There are not any ice creams which are expensive and taste bad.  Compare this to $\forall x, p(x) \vee \forall x, q(x)$ which is "Every ice cream is cheap or Every ice cream is expensive"

Comment: @JMoravitz I understand the "every x is -- or --" I dont understand the "every x is -- or every x is --" in the inclusive or sense

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip yeah but if the "or" is in the inclusive sense, we could write also "or everything is blue and red" and thats my problem

Comment: No the inclusive or here means everything is blue or everything is red or both everything is blue and everything is red.

Comment: To a person who absolutely loves ice cream and considers every ice cream to be delicious regardless of flavor or price, "every ice cream is delicious or every ice cream is cheap" is true since to him there does not exist an ice cream that isn't delicious.  Now.. suppose it was national ice cream day and every icecream was on sale.  In this case every ice cream is both cheap *and* delicious to him.  You might be causing problems for yourself by using examples where the two outcomes are usually thought of as being mutually exclusive, such as objects not usually being both red and blue.

Comment: @JMoravitz so saying "every ice cream is good or every ice cream is cheap" means "every ice cream is good or every ice cream is cheap or every ice cream is good and cheap"

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip yeah but how can everything be blue and everything be red

Comment: Yes, which depending on which universe you are considering as well as how exactly you define "good" or "cheap" may or may not be true.  If you were to talk only about the ice cream available in your favorite restaurant, maybe everything is both cheap and good.  You can get [gold leaf ice cream in japan](https://favy-jp.com/topics/775) which might not be cheap to you so if we were to expand the universe larger this might qualify as an ice cream which is not cheap.

Comment: Again, you seem to be fixating too much on an example where it doesn't necessarily make sense for both to happen simultaneously.  That doesn't prevent other examples from having both happen simultaneously.  That, or maybe you need to redefine what it means to "be blue" vs "be red".  Who is to say that an object can only be one color at a time.  Maybe the balls [looked like this](https://storage.googleapis.com/pricemandu.com/images/products/full/6d02f097de7763cc99527f23fb3648cf9ce290a8.jpg) and *are* such that all balls are blue and all balls are red simultaneously.

Comment: It can't, so that possibility doesn't occur and in this case, inclusive or is not different from exclusive or.

Comment: Whether or not an inclusive or *can* be replaced by an exclusive or without affecting the validity of a particular statement is not justification for actually performing the replacement, nor does it suggest that inclusive ors and exclusive ors are always equivalent.  There are certainly examples where leaving the or as inclusive helps to phrase an argument more cleanly while ignoring whether or not an exclusive or might have been valid in its place or not.  Further, there are statements with inclusive ors which might be true where having replaced with an exclusive or makes it false.

Comment: @JMoravitz so if I say "every square is white or every square is black or maybe both" that "or maybe both" means "or every square is black and white", now, does this mean that: every square has 2 colors, white and black , or it means that among all the squares I have there are only 2 colors, white and black ⬜⬛

Comment: Every square is white or every square is black (*or maybe both*) means that one of three scenarios is true:  Every square has white in it (*possibly more than just white, for example ⬜⬜⬜ or ⬜⬜ or  or similar but not ⬜⬛*), every square has black in it (*for example ⬛⬛⬛ or ⬛ or  or similar but not ⬜⬛*), or every square has both black and white in it (*the only example of which is  or similar*)

Comment: In the example "every square is white or every square is black (*or maybe both*)" you had that ⬜⬛ failed to satisfy that condition since it was false that every square was white since the third square wasn't, it was false that the every square was black since the first square wasn't, and it was also false that every square was both since neither the first nor the third squares were both.  On the other hand the statement "Every square is black or white" it is perfectly valid since indeed, among all of the squares, each square had black or white in it.

Comment: @JMoravitz I love you. thank you hallelujah haha

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in mathematics all "or"s are inclusive unless stated otherwise.

As to how they're different, consider a box with one red-but-not-blue ball and one blue-but-not-red ball *(or perhaps more intuitively, "Every natural number is odd or even" vs. "Either every natural number is odd or every natural number is even" - noting that no natural number is both odd and even)*.

Note that the inclusive/exclusive issue plays no role here: the point is that there is a "situation" in which one of the sentences is true but the other is false, so they're not equivalent. On the other hand we do have $$[\forall x(P(x))\vee\forall x(Q(x))]\implies \forall x(P(x)\vee Q(x)),$$ it's just that the converse fails.

Comment: in the sentence "every natural number is odd or every natural number is even" the "or" is in the exclusive sense, since a number can't be both even and odd

Comment: @cekami7844 not necessarily.  It could be replaced with an exclusive or and the validity of the statement is the same, but it doesn't necessarily need to be interpreted as the exclusive or.

Comment: @cekami7844 No, it's not - a priori it's inclusive, but *in light of additional information* we happen to know that it's equivalent to the exclusive disjunction in this case.